# Not expanding invalid branch in BOOST_CPP_IF

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

I have this macro (simplified from a real use case):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#define MY_MACRO(x) \
    BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_IS_BEGIN_PARENS(x), \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0,x),   \
        x)
```

It doesn't work. When passed a sequence, all is fine:

```
MY_MACRO((a)(b)(c)) // expands to `a`
```

But when passing a non-sequence, it breaks:

```
MY_MACRO(a) // expectation: expands to `a`
            // reality: preprocessor error
```

I understand why this happens. The preprocessor expands all arguments of `BOOST_PP_IF`. When the condition (the first argument) is false, the true branch (the second argument) is invalid. Even though the intent is to discard it, it still breaks compilation.

What is a proper way to address this problem? I could invent some homebrew macros, but surely Boost.Preprocessor should have some predefined facilities for this? I couldn't find any in [the guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/AppendixA-AnIntroductiontoPreprocessorMetaprogramming.html).

Comment: Can't test right now, but something like `BOOST_PP_EXPAND(BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_IS_BEGIN_PARENS(x), BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD, BOOST_PP_IDENTITY) (x))`?

Comment: @aschepler It leaves `BOOST_PP_EMPTY` in the output :( A simpler identity macro should work in this specific case, but what about the general case? In my real code the branches are more involved (can access more seq elements than just the head, again depending on the condition).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this transformation should work in most cases where the simplistic approach outlined above doesn't work.

Given a macro that is broken for the reason stated above:

```
 #define MY_MACRO(x, y, z) BOOST_PP_IF(some_condition(x, y, z), \
                                some text involving x y and z,  \
                                some other text involving x y and z)
```

one could rewrite it this way:

```
#define TRUE_BRANCH(x, y, z)   some text involving x y and z
#define FALSE_BRANCH(x, y, z)  some other text involving x y and z
#define MY_MACRO(x, y, z) \
          BOOST_PP_EXPAND(BOOST_PP_IF(some_condition(x, y, z), \
          TRUE_BRANCH, FALSE BRANCH)(x, y, z))
```

Comment: Thanks for @aschepler for the idea. I am still not sure this is the preferred Boost.Preprocessor way, but at least it doesn't look too bad!